# krpano html5 viewer on ipad

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, krpano

I'm trying to use the [KRPano](http://krpano.com/) html5 panorama viewer when users visit a certain page on a tablet/iPad. On desktop, I use the flash viewer and it works without problems:

```
embedpano({ swf: "/Files/Flash/krpano.swf", xml: "/Files/Flash/view.xml", target: "panview", id: "krpanoSWFObject", width: 1920, height: 1100, vars: settings });
```

where as `settings` is:

```
var settings = {};
settings["sphere"] = ImgSrc; // ImgSrc is a variable which contains the source of the image
settings["view.hlookat"] = 0.0;
settings["view.vlookat"] = 0.0;
settings["view.fov"] = 90;
settings["view.fovmin"] = 0;
settings["view.fovmax"] = 150;
```

So, I tried to set `html5: "auto"`, `html5: "only"`, and `html5: "prefer"`, but with no luck, when running it on iPad.

So does anyone know what to do? Would be a huge help...

Answer (score 0):

I hope you already solved this issue.

However, I mention my answer for other users. 
You should load krpano.js as well as krpano.swf.

just put  before embedpano() script.

Regarding Krpano, i recommend to use http://krpano.com/forum for more specific answers. Klaus, krpano developer, is answering some questions.